# How can I open the Contacts activity just to view the contact's information, not allowing the user to click (or touch) anything?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open the native Contact activity, not the Contacts list as I already have done that, but a particular contact information using the native activity.
The special requirement here is that all I want is to display the contact's information but not allowing the user to click anything.
I can open the activity with this code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode != 1) {
        return;
    }

    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }

    Uri selectedUserUri = data.getData();
    this.onContactSelected(selectedUserUri);
}

private void onContactsButtonClick() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI), 1);
}

private void onContactSelected(Uri selectedUserUri) {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, selectedUserUri), 2);
}
```

I need the user not to be able to click anything because that's not part of the functionalities of my application, in the worst case I would need the activity to report me the clicked phone number or e-mail address instead of opening the dialer or a web browser.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: did u want pick a contact from phonebook?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing and work as I want it, the problem comes after I get the selected contact shown, because if I click on any phone number it starts a phone call, and that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code for start pick contacts activity like this code write button click event contacts:

```
try
{
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
     intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
     startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

after get contact phone number below code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
      try
      {


      if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT)
      {         
          Cursor cursor =  managedQuery(intent.getData(), null, null, null, null);
          cursor.moveToNext();
          String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
           String  name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)); 
           String phone=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
           String phoneNumber="test";

          if ( phone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
              phone = "true";
          else
              phone = "false" ;

          if (Boolean.parseBoolean(phone)) 
          {
           Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
           while (phones.moveToNext()) 
           {
             phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
           }
           phones.close();
          }
          Toast.makeText(this, "You are selected Contact name "+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          if(phone_no.getText().length()!=0)
          {
              phone_no.setText(phone_no.getText().toString()+","+phoneNumber);
          }
          else
          {
              phone_no.setText(phoneNumber);
          }

      }
        }
      catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

this function pick a contact assign phone_no Editext this is not allow make a call!
Note:this function copy paste after onCreate() method  like below format:

```
@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ------------Your Code ---------
}
@Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
   {
       ------------
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, if i'm reading the code well that would effectively write the phone numbers of the selected contact in a TextView, but that's not actually what I need.
What I need is to open the native contact activity, but not allowing it to make a call. Of course I could take a screenshot of the activity and create one that looks exactly the same, but that'd be a lot of work and wouldn't be platform-independent.